# Mybatis association get value before set value

Tags: mybatis

When I declare an association in a mapper, I expect MyBatis to use the setter to set a new instance for this property.

What happens: MyBatis uses the getter (in the following example: getItem()) to get the value before it is set.

```
<association property="item" javaType="Element">
      ...
</association>
```

How can I tell Mybatis to create a new instance to set instead of using the one it gets with the getter.

Comment: how did you know mybatis call getter before it call setter?

Comment: Actually I found out because it crashed since a getter returned a null value which then was used by myBatis. Then I investigated.